# Стандартный вывод чисел

Tags: c

Никак не могу понять,что значит:

> "Вещественные числа выводите с 10 значимыми десятичными цифрами."

Имеется ввиду 10 знаков после запятой? То есть `printf("%.10lf",a)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Значащие цифры это кроме начальных нулей слева и до последней достоверной цифры. Фиксированное количество значащих цифр обеспечивают спецификатор `g` в альтернативной форме, т.е.

```
printf("%#.10lg",a);
```

и спецификатор `e`, но с на единицу меньшим параметром точности:

```
printf("%#.9le",a);
```

Простой `g` без `#` удаляет завершающие нули после запятой, которые стоит считать значащими.

Comment: А может правильнее было бы printf("%.9le")? Судя по http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf

Comment: А если я напишу : printf("%11lf",a) -я буду прав?(Здесь 10 количество цифр до запятой +количество цифр после запятой и потом +1 для запятой . Пулучаю 11)?

Comment: @mango44 нет, `f` не меняет количество цифр после запятой, если вы его не указали, оно равно 6. 11 - это общая длина, число цифр перед запятой зависит от целой части числа и будет дополнено слева пробелами если общая длина меньше 11, но длина может быть и больше 11. например для миллиона будет выведено 13 цифр, а для единицы - 7 и три пробела в начале.

Comment: То есть значащие цифры это все циыры(до и почле запятой)?

Comment: @mango44 не всегда, если вы напишите `printf("%011f", 1.)` ведущие 3 нуля будут незначащие.

Comment: @sercxjo простите за тупость,но я все равно не понимаю...Вот в числе 123.12 значащих цифр две или пять?

Comment: @mango44 - 5. Правило - приведите число к виду `0.12312e+3` (до запятой - обязательно 0, 1-й знак после запятой - обязательно не 0) - количество знаков после запятой и есть количество значащих цифр.

Comment: @mango44, в 123.12 imho 5 значащих цифр. Откровенно, не помню всех этих тонкостей с форматами. М.б. проще всего (но, наверняка все скажут, что неправильно) вывести в строку `sprintf(str, "%.10g", ...)`  и рассчитать все самому пробегая по строке и считая цифры (чтобы отрезать лишние после `.`)

Comment: @mango44, я тут чуть поигрался с выводом %.10g -- похоже, то что надо. Может потребоваться лишь **добавлять** нули после '.' (или саму '.' и нули после нее для целых чисел). А Вы сами попробуйте и все станет ясно.

Answer (score 3):

Обычно под значащими цифрами имеют в виду цифры, отличные от нуля. Например, в числе 1.45 три значащих цифры.